# Why does this double buffering scheme generate audible clicks each time the audio file is read from disk?

Tags: c++, audio

The following double-buffering scheme seems like it should work to me, but for some reason there's an audible click every time the for-loops starts again at the top.

Here is a test wav file you can use: https://github.com/JoshuaD84/jwaveform/blob/master/test4.wav, but the bug is not specific to any one test file.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bitset>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

HWAVEOUT hWaveOut = 0;
WAVEFORMATEX wfx;

int main() {
  wfx = { WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, 2, 44100, 176400, 4, 16, 0 };
  waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);
  
  const int increment = 80000;
  WAVEHDR* oldHeader = nullptr;
  for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
    std::ifstream inStream;
    inStream.open("test4.wav", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    char headerInfo[44]; //get past the wav header to the audio data
    inStream.read(headerInfo, 44);
    while (true) {
      char* buffer = new char[increment];
      inStream.read(buffer, increment);
      DWORD bytesRead = inStream.gcount();
      if (bytesRead <= 0) {
        break;
      } 
      WAVEHDR* header = new WAVEHDR{ buffer, bytesRead, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
      waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
      waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
      if (oldHeader != nullptr) {
        while (!(oldHeader->dwFlags & WHDR_DONE)) {
          Sleep(1);
        }
        waveOutUnprepareHeader(hWaveOut, oldHeader, sizeof(oldHeader));
        delete[] oldHeader->lpData;
        delete oldHeader;
      }
      oldHeader = header;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure it's something stupid, but I've been tinkering with it for two nights and I can't figure out where I'm making the mistake.

(For your convenience: I'm able to compile this at a 64-bit VS developer command prompt as a single file with the command `cl /EHsc test.cpp`).

Notes:

1. I have checked the file and it both starts and ends at 0, so the clip isn't caused by the shape of the audio.
2. If i trim ~100 bytes off the end of the last buffer of the file, I don't get a clip.
3. If I read the header `subChunkSize` field, regardless of the file, it reports the data field being 312 bytes larger than what I am able to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the double-buffering scheme; that's fine.

The problem is that you are assuming that the rest of the audio file is valid audio data, but there is junk data past the audio data at the end of this file. When you play that junk data, it sounds like a click.

In order to avoid the click, only read as many bytes as specified in Subchunk2Size, as specified in the [wav format](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/).